# How to exclude dependencies from BOOT-INF/classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I have a spring boot project and I get this error when I try to build it:

```
> gradle build
:processResources
:compileJava
:classes
:jar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jar'.
> archive contains more than 65535 entries.

  To build this archive, please enable the zip64 extension.
  See: https://docs.gradle.org/3.5.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip:zip64

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Ok, I added the `zip64 = true` option to the jar task in the gradle configuration.
Now it can build the jar successfully but when I try to execute the jar, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.<init>(JarLauncher.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.AsciiBytes.<init>(AsciiBytes.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.load(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryParser.parseEntries(CentralDirectoryParser.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryParser.parse(CentralDirectoryParser.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createArchive(Launcher.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.<init>(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:40)
    ... 2 more
```

It turned out that SpringBoot doesn't even support the zip64 format, so I had to make further investigation.
Where do the 65535+ entries come from? Obviously these come from dependencies, because the issue exists since
I added a new dependency in the build.gradle file. While examining the zip64 jar, I have found that
all the dependency classes! are under the BOOT-INF/classes folder.

As I understand, the structure must look like

```
BOOT-INF/
    classes/
        <only this application's compiled classes>
    libs/
        <all the dependency jars>
```

But my classes folder has all the dependency jars "extracted" to it.
([As you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlUyg.png))

I extracted the jar, removed all the dependency classes from this folder and rezipped it. ([Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TtQw.png))
*This way it can be run without any problem*, so I'm sure these files are unneccesary.

**Can somebody help me, how to exclude these dependency classes from the structure? Thank you in advance!**

Here's my relevant gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

ext.springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

configurations {
    provided.all*.exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
}

mainClassName = 'com.path.to.my.MainClass'

repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
    maven { 
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" 
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/"
    }
}

jar {
//zip64 = true
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { 
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
        } 
    }
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": mainClassName)
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0'   
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'javax.json:javax.json-api:1.0'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.4'
    compile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:4.0.3'
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
    ......
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: what if you drop the customized `jar` task and use the provided `bootRepackage` task [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging)?

Comment: bootRepackage already runs in the end of the build process, but if I disable the jar task, the result is unfortunately the same. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I'd expect the suggestion from @zapl to use `bootRepackage` to work. All of your dependencies' classes are appearing unzipped in your jar file as that's what your configuration of the `jar` task has told Gradle to do. Perhaps you need it for a reason that's not included in your question, but I suspect you can remove all of the customisation of the `jar` task.

Comment: Thank you! It really works. I can't believe those lines didn't catch my attention. The disabled jar task didn't produced a new jar, this is why i thought it's the same. By deleting the "from" block of the jar task configuration I got the desired result. I don't know its origin, i suppose it's an early try for creating a fat jar, but it works without it. So thanks to both of you and feel free to write an "upvotable" answer.